# Importing Ionic ToastController into TS Class

Tags: typescript, class, ionic-framework, ionic3

I don't know if what I want to do is possible or even smart. Am working on an Ionic 3 project and I would like to house "Toast" functionality in a class so that I can establish default values and access it from anywhere.

1. How could I access methods from the ToastController imported from 'ionic-angular' within my class definition? Passing it in via the constructor means I have to pass it when I want to create new objects using my class which doesn't make sense to me.
2. There are two methods in ToastController `create()` and `present()`. What would be really cool is if whenever I create a new instance of a Toast object by calling `new Toast("My Toast Message")` from elsewhere in the application, the toast message appears in the UI as expected. I don't know if that's possible or if I need to return the 'created' object as I've outlined in the code.

Thanks

```
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class Toast {

    private toast: {
        message: string;
        duration: number;
        showCloseButton: boolean;
        position: string;
        cssClass: string;
    }

    public toastCtrl: ToastController; // this doesn't do anything I don't think

    constructor(message: string, 
                duration: number = 3000, 
                showCloseButton: boolean = true, 
                position: string = 'top',
                cssClass: string = 'brand-toast') {

        this.toast = {
            message: message,
            duration: duration,
            showCloseButton: showCloseButton,
            position: position,
            cssClass: cssClass,
        }

        return this.toastCtrl.create(this.toast);

        // would be cool to instead call this:
        // this.toastCtrl.create(this.toast).present();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First your toast must be a provider and you can use it wherever you want.

```
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ToastProvider
```

You can create methods to customize a toast or call a default toast

```
private isShowToast: boolean = false;

public showCustomToast(toast: any) {
    if (this.toast !== undefined && this.isShowToast) {
      this.toast.dismiss();
      this.isShowToast = false;
    }

    let customToast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: toast.message,
      duration: toast.duration
    });

    customToast.present();
    this.isShowToast = true;
  }

public showDefaultToast(){
    if (this.toast !== undefined && this.isShowToast) {
      this.toast.dismiss();
      this.isShowToast = false;
    }  

    this.toast.present();
    this.isShowToast = true;
}
```

Don't forget to import your `ToastProvider` as a provider into your component and app.module.ts